# Interior and closure of $\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\} $ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$

Tags: general-topology

What is the interior and closure of $A = \left\{  \frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}  \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\} $ ?

I suppose that in both cases $\mbox{int}A = \emptyset$. Now closure:

- in $\mathbb{R}  \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\} $

we have $$\left( \mathbb{R}  \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\} \right)  \setminus A = ( - \infty,0)  \cup (1,+\infty) \cup  \bigcup_{n=1}^{ \infty } \left(  \frac{1}{n} ,  \frac{1}{n+1} \right) $$

On right side every set is open so $\left( \mathbb{R}  \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\} \right)  \setminus A$ is open hence $A$ is closed. Then we have $\mbox{cl}A = A$

But from second side if we take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ we have that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and of course $0 \not\in A$ so $A$ is not closure.

Where is mistake?

- in $\mathbb{R}$

Now I'm really confused so I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made no mistake in the beginning: $A$ is closed in $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, because its complement is open, just as you said. The fact that $\left\langle\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle\to 0$ is irrelevant, because $0$ is not in the space $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

That sequence **is** relevant when you consider $A$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$: it shows that $A$ is not closed in $\Bbb R$ and furthermore that $0\in\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}A$. Is anything else in $\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}A$?

Comment: Of course, $A \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}A$ so we have that $ \left\{ 0 \right\} \cup A  \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}A$. How can I check, is anything else in $\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb R}A$?

Comment: @Thomas: Everything else is in the open set $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\setminus A$.

Answer (score 1):

As you claimed, both of cases, $intA=\emptyset$

In the first case, you're right

In the second one, in $\mathbb{R}$, $ClA=A\cup$ {$0$} as every neighborbood of $0$ has non-empty intersection with $A$.